# What is the difference between coupled HMM's viterbi algorithm and tranditional HMM's viterbi algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-model, viterbi-algorithm

Can anyone show me what is the difference between coupled HMM's viterbi algorithm and tranditional HMM's viterbi algorithm? Is there any examples?